# Upload de arquivos com PHP não reconhece

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando fazer o upload de imagens com o PHP e Ajax mas o resultado diz que é um valor indefinido

Código Javascript

```
$('form[name="update-user"]').submit(function(){
        form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'switch/painel.php',
            data: form.serialize() + '&acao=update_user',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.find('.load').fadeIn('fast');
            },
            success: function(resp){
                alert(resp);
            },
            complete: function(){
                form.find('.load').fadeOut('fast')
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Segue o código da página

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" name="update-user" class="form-horizontal" accept="image/*" method="POST">
         <input type="file" name="user-profile" id="file-profile">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar dados">
    </form>
```

Arquivo controller

```
case 'update_user':
    var_dump($_FILES['user-profile']);
break;
```

Resultado: **undefined index: user-profile**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fazer upload apenas com jQuery.ajax e PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42823/fazer-upload-apenas-com-jquery-ajax-e-php)

Comment: Relacionado: [Erro ao enviar Upload com Ajax](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77020/erro-ao-enviar-upload-com-ajax?rq=1)

Comment: Relacionado: [Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar arquivos com ajax recomendo você usar jquery-forms (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) me economizou muito tempo e suporte em muitos navegadores.

Caso você não queira utilizar jquery nem plugins, já consegui de uma forma fácil mas restritiva a navegadores mais novos com html5 e o objeto formData (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) neste link está bem explicado como fazer inclusive com php.

E finalizando no lugar de fazer:

```
var_dump($_FILES['user-profile']);
```

tente fazer:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Assim você vai conseguir ver se tem alguma coisa no array talvez com outro nome, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Agradecemos sua vontade de colaborar com a comunidade, mas talvez seja interessante ler o texto [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42) O principal problema é que, se porventura, o link da resposta deixar de existir, a resposta perde o sentido por completo. Para contornar isso, verifique junto ao conteúdo do link os principais pontos que sejam válidos à pergunta e descreve-os aqui, mantendo o link apenas como um material de apoio.