# Enviar array de Objetos como parametro Ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js

Eu tenho um array de objetos composto da seguinte forma:

```
{file: File(871699), x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2, …}
```

Cada casa do vetor tem um elemento como o descrito acima, e o primeiro parametro, o file é uma imagem que tem os seguintes dados:

```
file:File(871699) {name: "tumblr_lxjy8kfFeQ1qh59n0o1_500.gif", lastModified: 1518121346035, lastModifiedDate: Thu Feb 08 2018 18:22:26 GMT-0200 (-02), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 871699, …}
```

Eu gostaria de passar esse array por uma chamada ajax, mas não consigo.
O meu código é esse:

```js
function uploadFiles(formData) {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/foto',
        type: 'POST',
        data: arrayObj,
        contentType: false,
        success: () => {
            console.log("Sucesso!!");
        }
    });
}
```

E no servidor eu recebo da seguinte forma:

```js
application.post('/admin/foto', (req, res) => { 
  application.controllers.admin.albums.uploadFotos(application, req, res);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dê um `JSON.stringify` nos dados.

```
function uploadFiles(formData) {
    const email = "blablablabla";

    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/foto',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(arrayObj), // <<-- Stringify
        contentType: false,
        success: () => {
            console.log("Sucesso!!");
        }
    });
}
```

Suponho que você esteja utilizando o `bodyParser`, então seus dados estarão no `req.body`:

```
application.post('/admin/foto', (req, res) => { 
  console.log(req.body); // <<-- array de objetos
  application.controllers.admin.albums.uploadFotos(application, req, res);
});
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso, mas ao fazer isso o objeto file contido dentre do vetor é perdido, ele fica como se estivesse vazio

Comment: Você quer fazer upload desses arquivos? Se for, não vai funcionar nunca...

Comment: Sim. Eu não to utilizando o formData porque preciso passar também o x, y, width  e height que é calculado em outra função. Por isso coloquei em um array de objetos, porque ai passo a imagem e esses valores relacionados juntos

Comment: Entendi @LaisAguiar, você pode utilizar o _Header_ pra passar essas informações, ou criar fields no _formdata_ pra colocar essas informações. Passar somente os objetos não vai funcionar. Dê uma olhada [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42824/8493) e [nesse tutorial](https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/), talvez te ajude.

Comment: Obrigada @KaduAmaral passando pelo header eu consegui fazer o que eu precisava!! Valeu mesmo